# How to control the outgoing IP of a JDBC connection in Java?

Tags: java, jdbc, tcp, ip

From the list of all available IP address of a Localhost, how to control or choose the IP in which the JDBC connection is made to the server, through java program?

Comment: For what purpose? IP will already choose the interface with the least cost to the target.

Comment: I need to simulate a scenario where the server is hit with different IP address though they all emerge from the same system. To replicate a real time scenario. Not to control the cost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* that it is possible.

The choice of the interface (NIC) to use when sending out-going network packets is determined by the routing configuration, and implemented *within* the operating system.  The NIC chosen will determine the "source" IP address that the remote server sees.  AFAIK, a normal user application has no way to influence the routing.  It is certainly not possible using the standard Java SE libraries.

The Android platform does allow an app to configure network routing, but I don't think it allows you to do this on a per-connection basis.

Comment: What if many IP address are assigned to the same NIC(only one NIC is present) through IP aliasing? could it be controlled then?
Thanks.